# Regex Match Of Field Values Within a String

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Suppose I have the following string:

```
Field1 = "Test"; Field2 = "Test"; Field3 = "Blah"; Field4 = "BlahBlah"
```

I am thinking of how I can write a regex expression I can use in *.NET/C#* where `RegEx.IsMatch(...)` would return `TRUE` if the *value of Field1* = *the value of Field2* and `FALSE` otherwise. Can't think of a way to do this... Any ideas?

Comment: I don't find this question particularly clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [back references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
@"Field1 = (""\w+"");.*Field2 = \1"
```

Comment: Awesome dude! Just what I was looking for. Never used back references before!

Comment: Is there a way to make this order indifferent? (i.e. would still match if Field2 is followed by Field1)

Comment: @denis you could swap the order in a new regex and run it again. but you're going to keep running into annoyances like that. see my answer below for the super flexible way of handling this.

Comment: You can add an alternative `|Field2 = (""\w+"");.*Field1 = \1`. Or if you are sure that the names will be used only one time, you could make the number indifferent: `Field[12] = (""\w+"");.*Field[21] = \1`

Comment: 1 goal for understanding the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

as @ndn mentions, this is possible with backreferences, but trying to do this wholly within regex is like using the end of a screwdriver to pound in a nail. I think you'd be much better off parsing the whole thing with regex and using C# to analyze the results

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(myInputString, @"
    (?<fieldName>\w+)
    \s*
    =
    \s*
    ""(?<value>[^""]+)""
    ;?", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

//obviously what you do with the matches can get as complicated as you want
//but you have infinite flexibility now that you're in C#.
var field1Value = matches.Cast<Match>().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Groups["fieldName"].Value == "Field1").Value;
var field2Value = matches.Cast<Match>().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Groups["fieldName"].Value == "Field2").Value;

return field1Value == field2Value;
```

Note: in c# you have to escape `"` by using `""` in a verbatim string (a string starting with `@"`) and not `\"` as you would in a normal string.

Here is what the matches would look like in http://www.regexpixie.com

[image]

Comment: Similarly you don't need to use regular expressions to parse either.  Just use `string.Split`.

Comment: @juharr sure you don't *have* to but it'll make it easier and flexible. if using split, you'd have to split on semicolon, then on equal sign, then trim whitespace then trim quote marks. parsing is where regex shines, imperative logic like conditionals it doesn't do so great with (although you can shoehorn it to make it work sometimes)